# event.stopPropagation() или event.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Есть массив,в цикле каждый элемент оборачивается в `li`,а затем в `a`
ссылка ведет на `div`в первый раз все работает хорошо,со 2 раза alert начинает вылезать 2 раза.

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

не помогают

```
$('body').on('tap', 'ul li', function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();

 alert("test");
 })
```

Comment: Вы добавляете новый callback при каждом нажатии, потому и алерты и плодятся ))

Comment: Будьте добры,подскажите как избавиться от этого)

Comment: function _my_tap() { alert("test"); }
     $('body').on('tap', 'ul li', _my_tap);

Comment: все равно по 2 раза

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы навешиваете event onTap каждый раз, при этом не удаляете старый event

Попробуйте:

```
$('body').off('tap').on('tap', 'ul li', function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
  alert("test");
})
```